# Google map api : Change the size of countries

Tags: google-maps

I would like to change the size of the countries on a google map. For instance, I would like to shrink France and expand the USA as in http://www.vox.com/xpress/2014/9/20/6661175/the-population-of-the-internet-in-one-map

Is it possible?

Cheers,

Aurelien

Comment: Yes it is possible.  You would need to create your own map tiles and use the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Just to make sure I get your point. Tiles are images of map you inject in Google Maps?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes